# Trouble building kernel module during nvidia-driver install

Tags: linux, drivers, debian, kernel, nvidia

I am running Debian 10 with a kernel that I built from source. When I attempt to install nvidia-driver from buster-backports with "sudo apt -t buster-backports install nvidia-driver", it fails with:

```
Building initial module for 5.15.12s1avl2-lowlatency
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.15.12s1avl2-lowlatency (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-current/460.73.01/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-kernel-dkms (--configure):
 installed nvidia-kernel-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-driver:
 nvidia-driver depends on nvidia-kernel-dkms (= 460.73.01-1~bpo10+1) | nvidia-kernel-460.73.01; however:
  Package nvidia-kernel-dkms is not configured yet.
  Package nvidia-kernel-460.73.01 is not installed.
  Package nvidia-kernel-dkms which provides nvidia-kernel-460.73.01 is not configured yet.
```

When I consult make.log while it reports errors but I don't understand what is wrong. Here is the log from the first error:

```
make[3]: *** [/home/iain/kernels/scarlett-gen2-5.15.12s1/scripts/Makefile.build:277: /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-current/460.73.01/build/nvidia/os-interface.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
   ./tools/objtool/objtool orc generate  --module  --no-fp   --retpoline  --uaccess  /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-current/460.73.01/build/nvidia/os-mlock.o
   ./tools/objtool/objtool orc generate  --module  --no-fp   --retpoline  --uaccess  /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-current/460.73.01/build/nvidia/os-pci.o
```

And the second:

```
make[2]: *** [/home/iain/kernels/scarlett-gen2-5.15.12s1/Makefile:1868: /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-current/460.73.01/build] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.12s1avl2-lowlatency'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:219: __sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/iain/kernels/scarlett-gen2-5.15.12s1'
make: *** [Makefile:80: modules] Error 2
```

I have uploaded the entire log to https://escuta.org/webtemp/make.log

Can anyone please help?

UPDATE: If I try to install the required nvidia-kernel-460.73.01, the installation prints:

```
Note, selecting 'nvidia-kernel-dkms' instead of 'nvidia-kernel-460.73.01'
nvidia-kernel-dkms is already the newest version (460.73.01-1~bpo10+1).
nvidia-kernel-dkms set to manually installed.
```